# While creating view in Hive SQL, getting error as duplicate column present

Tags: sql, hive

create view comb as
select * from dept d join
dept_part p on d.dept_name = p.dept_name;

Error Message as "Duplicate column name: dept_name"

Comment: Your view contains two dept_name fields (from dept and from dept_part). Write all fields directly instead of "*"

Comment: in case of such statement, always use columns spent out and not *. you can control column name and sequence.

Comment: create view mrg as select d.dept_id,d.dept_name,d.emp_name,d.salary,p.dept_name,p.emp_name,p.salary,p.dept_id from dept d join dept_part p on d.dept_name = p.dept_name;  No luck, still the same error message.

Comment: Because you still have 2 columns with the same name (dept_id). Presumably they both have the same value in any row so you don't need both of them? If you did need both of them then you would need to alias one (or preferably both) of them. Prefixing the columns with the table alias allows the SELECT to run but doesn't create a unique column name - so the View cannot be created. Using p.dept_id doesn't result in a column called "p.dept_id" being created, it results in a column called "dept_id" being created